# NServiceBus MSMQ, How to Stop message transfer to Error Queue

Tags: nservicebus, msmq

I am using NServiceBus for a proof of concept. I am using it with MSMQ. I Have a Web Application which send a message. This message will be handled by a subscriber or message handler. When i shutdown the message handler, message will be send to Error Queue after few retries.

I don't want to send it to error queue, i want to keep message in Input queue as long as Handler is again online and process this message automatically from input queue. If message can not be processed from handler due to any error, it must transfer message to error queue.

Here is my configuration in MVC application  Global.asax

```
private void ConfigureServiceBus()
    {
        var endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("Samples.Mvc.Endpoint");

        endpointConfiguration.UseSerialization<JsonSerializer>();
        endpointConfiguration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
        endpointConfiguration.UseTransport<MsmqTransport>();
        endpointConfiguration.SendFailedMessagesTo("error");
        endpointConfiguration.AuditProcessedMessagesTo("audit");
        var recoverability = endpointConfiguration.Recoverability();
        recoverability.Delayed(
            delayed =>
            {
                delayed.NumberOfRetries(2);
                delayed.TimeIncrease(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            });
        endpointConfiguration.EnableInstallers();
        endpoint = Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        //var endpointInstance = Endpoint.Start(endpointConfiguration).ConfigureAwait(false);
        var mvcContainerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        mvcContainerBuilder.RegisterInstance(endpoint);
        // Register MVC controllers.
        mvcContainerBuilder.RegisterControllers(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
        var mvcContainer = mvcContainerBuilder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(mvcContainer));
    }
```

This is the part in Controller where i send message to endpoint.

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Contact(ContactModel c)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    var message = new ContactMessage()
                    {
                        Comment = c.Comment,
                        Email = c.Email,
                        FirstName = c.FirstName,
                        LastName = c.LastName,
                        TransectionId = Guid.NewGuid()
                    };

                    await endpoint.Send("Samples.Mvc.Endpoint", message).ConfigureAwait(false);

                    return View("Success");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return View("Error");
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

My goal is to keep unhandled messages in input queue as long as message handler is not back on work. currently if message handler is down, it send messages after retries to Error Queue.

I am using NServiceBus  6.x

thanks in advance

Comment: That's exactly what should happen. Could you provide your 'handler' side's code and configuration as well?

Comment: If you email support at particular.net I'd be happy to get on a call with you and help you with your POC, address the email to Sean Farmar

Comment: I thinks you can play around with your retry mechanism. I have also experienced this issue. we always replay the messages in different batches using QueueExplorer if transport is MSMQ.